# Browsers hang when loading web pages

Tags: windows-vista, firefox, browser, internet-explorer-8

HP Laptop with Windows Vista Home Premium, Service Pack 2.

Problem affects IE8 and Firefox.

When attempting to browse most web sites, browser loads web site title in browser's title bar, then displays "Waiting for site url" and never completes loading the page.

Able to connect to www.google.com with no problems.

Unable to connect to www.carbonwy.com, www.wsj.com, www.cnn.com, www.microsoft.com, etc.

Other PCs on same subnet are all able to connect to these sites without any problem.

nslookup resolves all of these sites without any problem, so DNS does not appear to be the problem.

Windows Firewall is disabled.

Norton 360 was previously installed but has been uninstalled. No other firewall software is installed.

IE8 Protected Mode is off. IE8 advanced settings have been reset. IE8 user settings have been reset. After reset, IE8 tries to connect to http://hp-laptop.aol.com and go.microsoft.com but same symptoms persist. Title bar loads, then nothing.

System has been restarted numerous times.

Running out of ideas. Please help!

Comment: What does Firebug's net panel show during the page load process? (http://getfirebug.com/)

You might also double-check the hosts file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file#Content_and_location), just to make sure.  It's probably not that, though, since nslookup works.

Comment: Can get to getfirebug.com, but can't get to addons.mozilla.org.  Still trying to figure out a way to get firebug installed.

hosts file is completely generic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does sound like the old MTU problem that I've seen crop up a number of times.

You can find some more background information on MTU [here](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/MTU.htm).

There is a handy tool on [Zen Internet](http://www.zen.co.uk/support/tools.aspx)'s website which allows you to modify your MTU setting for ADSL connections.

Depending on your type of internet connection, you may need to manually [determine your best MTU](http://www.speedguide.net/read_articles.php?id=156) setting and then [set it from the command prompt](http://www.kitz.co.uk/adsl/vistaMTU.htm).

Comment: That did it!  I set the MTU to 1400 and everything works now!  Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Norton left behind something which is causing a breaking problem on your machine.  Norton is notorious for its products failing to correctly clean up after themselves on uninstalls.  I had Norton Security 2009 installed on one workstation.  After I uninstalled it, while I could still surf the web, I couldn't get any other security program to install or work after that.  I finally gave up and did a windows repair which fixed my issue.